# Get the sharedpreference data in an adapter

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, adapter

Googled and tried my whole day about getting the sharedpreference data in my adapter. I have an `SharedPreferenceManager` class

```
public class SharedPrefManager {
static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
static Context mContext;

static int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "sessionPref";

static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public SharedPrefManager (Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}

public void saveUID(Context context,String uid){
    mContext = context;
    sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("UID", uid);
    editor.commit();
}
public String getUID(){
    sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString("UID", "");
}
public void clear(){
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
}
}
```

I call the `SharedPrefManager` in any activity like this

```
public SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;
public String uid
```

and in `onCreate()`

```
sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(mContext);
uid = sharedPrefManager.getUID();
```

now, how to get the same data in an adapter since the below code gives error in any adapter

```
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(context);
public String uid = sharedPrefManager.getUID();
```

Here is my `Adapter Class`

```
public class MyCommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCommentAdapter.MyCommentHolder> {
Context context;
private List<MyComment> commentList;

//Here I get the null pointer error
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(context);
public String uid = sharedPrefManager.getUID();
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference1=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(uid).child("Comment");
```

int the Last line of code I want to access the database with the uid, that is why I need the uid value from shared preference

```
public MyCommentAdapter(Context context, List<MyComment> commentList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.commentList = commentList;
}
```

Comment: sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(context); put this line in constructor

Comment: I stored the data when the user logs in, now I want to retrieve the uid in the adapter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **`context is null`**. Try after assigning it

```
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager ;
public String uid ;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference1;
public MyCommentAdapter(Context context, List<MyComment> commentList) {
    this.context = context;
    sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(context);
    this.commentList = commentList;
    uid = sharedPrefManager.getUID();
    mDatabaseReference1=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(uid).child("Comment");

}
```

Comment: I have Updated My question, please have a look

Comment: @BikramNath You can add that line in constructor after getting uid. Check my answer

Comment: @BikramNath happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to **initialize** your **sharedPreferancne** class in the `constructor` of the `adpater`. Something like this:

```
private CustomSharedPreferences customSharedPreferences;
```

and then in your constructor:

```
public MyCommentAdapter(Context context, List<MyComment> commentList) 
{
this.context = context;
this.customSharedPrefernces = new CustomSharedPreferences(context);
this.commentList = commentList;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look @Umair

Comment: @BikramNath I can't see where you initialize your sharedPref class in constructor ?

Comment: Thank you so much Umair. I got the answer from you too, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Happy to help. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not a right thing to this kind of things inside of your RecyclerView adapter, it slows down you **scrolling performance** and it's violating **SRP**.

BUT

you can simply **inject** you SharedPrefManager into you adapter :

```
public class MyCommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCommentAdapter.MyCommentHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<MyComment> commentList;

    private SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;
    public String uid;

    public MyCommentAdapter(Context context, List<MyComment> commentList, SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.commentList = commentList;
        this.sharedPrefManager = sharedPrefManager
        this.uid = sharedPrefManager.getUID();
    }
}
```

and then in your activity when you are creating the adapter you can inject sharedPrefManager in it's constructor.

Comment: now I want to use the uid in the same adapter class, to get the reference to the database as suppose `databaseref.child(uid)`, how to achieve that? that is why I need the uid the adapter

Comment: Thank you mehdi for your time. really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SP {
    /**
     * @param mContext
     * @param key
     * @param value
     */
    public static void savePreferences(Context mContext, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param keyValue
     * @return
     */
    public static String getPreferences(Context context, String keyValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(keyValue, "");
    }

    /**
     * @param mContext
     */
    public static void removeAllSharedPreferences(Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear().apply();
    }
}
```